# Custom query methods in NSManagedObejct

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to add a custom query method in a subclass of NSManagedObject?

I have a domain model called User, and a domain model called Message. I've set it up so that a user has a To-Many relationship to messages. So in my app, when i do

```
[userInstance messages];
```

it returns me a NSSet of messages that belong to that user, which is perfect. But the Message domain model also has an "active" field which is a boolean.

I want to create a new method on the domain model that says

```
- (NSSet *)activeMessages
```

which, obviously, is a method that only return messages with active = true. I know I could do

```
[userInstance messages];
```

then just loop through and remove all the ones which are active = false, but that seems a bit inefficient. Seems like a waste to fetch all, then filter. I would rather just filter it out in the query.

The only other way I can think of, is to somehow get a hold of the NSManagedObjectContext inside the domain model to manually do the query.

Is that the best way? or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could try to use NSFetchRequest like this:

```
- (NSSet *)activeMessages inManagedContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user = %@ AND active = %@",self,YES];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *activeMessages = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return activeMessages;

}
```

Comment: cool, that makes sense. is that the general best practice in iOS programming? I come more from the java background and working with spring framework, where i'd inject the repo/datasource once via the container, and just use that reference to query the database for all methods.

Comment: Yes, i thnk it's quite convinient for Core Data usage,maybe someone can correct me, but i really feel like that.And Core Data is really a great framework.

Comment: But,although,you can try to use your getter and sort it,because i am not absoluetly sure what's behind the hood of apples getters,so it could be somehowmore efficient,then making your own NSFetch.

Comment: cool, i'll wait a day or two more and see if anyone else has any thoughts. but that was my same thought, i was wondering how those getters work under the hood too. was hoping there was some inherited methods or objects i can reuse without passing in a managed object context. thanks a lot Nikita.

Comment: so i did more research on this. silly me, to get a reference to the managed object context, all i need to do is do [self managedObjectContext]. so yeah there's no need to pass the context in.